# Predicting a class variable using XGBoost in R

Tags: r, prediction, xgboost

I am new to R and I want to predict the Class variable in my test set using XGBoost. My training data set looks as follows.

```
> str(train)
'data.frame':   5000 obs. of  37 variables:
 $ ID   : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ A1   : num  0.36 0.33 0.33 0.31 0.33 0.31 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 ...
 $ A2   : num  0.45 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.37 0.37 0.4 0.4 0.35 0.37 ...
 $ A3   : num  0.47 0.42 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.38 0.42 0.42 0.38 0.38 ...
 $ A4   : num  0.37 0.31 0.33 0.31 0.31 0.3 0.33 0.34 0.3 0.3 ...
 $ A5   : num  0.33 0.33 0.31 0.33 0.31 0.31 0.3 0.31 0.3 0.3 ...
 $ A6   : num  0.4 0.4 0.4 0.37 0.37 0.4 0.4 0.38 0.37 0.38 ...
 $ A7   : num  0.42 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.38 0.4 0.42 0.42 0.38 0.4 ...
 $ A8   : num  0.31 0.33 0.31 0.31 0.3 0.31 0.34 0.31 0.3 0.28 ...
 $ A9   : num  0.33 0.31 0.33 0.31 0.31 0.3 0.31 0.3 0.3 0.3 ...
 $ A10  : num  0.4 0.4 0.37 0.37 0.4 0.4 0.38 0.37 0.38 0.37 ...
 $ A11  : num  0.4 0.4 0.4 0.38 0.4 0.4 0.42 0.4 0.4 0.35 ...
 $ A12  : num  0.33 0.31 0.31 0.3 0.31 0.31 0.31 0.3 0.28 0.3 ...
 $ A13  : num  0.4 0.36 0.33 0.33 0.33 0.3 0.31 0.31 0.31 0.3 ...
 $ A14  : num  0.49 0.44 0.4 0.39 0.39 0.39 0.42 0.44 0.37 0.36 ...
 $ A15  : num  0.52 0.46 0.41 0.41 0.41 0.41 0.46 0.46 0.41 0.41 ...
 $ A16  : num  0.4 0.33 0.32 0.31 0.32 0.32 0.35 0.35 0.29 0.29 ...
 $ A17  : num  0.36 0.33 0.33 0.33 0.3 0.3 0.31 0.31 0.3 0.3 ...
 $ A18  : num  0.44 0.4 0.39 0.39 0.39 0.39 0.44 0.42 0.36 0.37 ...
 $ A19  : num  0.46 0.41 0.41 0.41 0.41 0.42 0.46 0.44 0.41 0.39 ...
 $ A20  : num  0.33 0.32 0.31 0.32 0.32 0.33 0.35 0.33 0.29 0.31 ...
 $ A21  : num  0.33 0.33 0.33 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.31 0.31 0.3 0.3 ...
 $ A22  : num  0.4 0.39 0.39 0.39 0.39 0.4 0.42 0.37 0.37 0.36 ...
 $ A23  : num  0.41 0.41 0.41 0.41 0.42 0.46 0.44 0.39 0.39 0.39 ...
 $ A24  : num  0.32 0.31 0.32 0.32 0.33 0.35 0.33 0.31 0.31 0.29 ...
 $ A25  : num  0.4 0.35 0.33 0.33 0.33 0.33 0.31 0.31 0.29 0.29 ...
 $ A26  : num  0.49 0.47 0.42 0.39 0.39 0.4 0.42 0.4 0.36 0.36 ...
 $ A27  : num  0.53 0.5 0.44 0.41 0.41 0.41 0.44 0.41 0.38 0.38 ...
 $ A28  : num  0.41 0.39 0.34 0.31 0.31 0.31 0.34 0.33 0.29 0.28 ...
 $ A29  : num  0.35 0.33 0.33 0.33 0.33 0.31 0.31 0.31 0.29 0.31 ...
 $ A30  : num  0.47 0.42 0.39 0.39 0.4 0.42 0.4 0.4 0.36 0.34 ...
 $ A31  : num  0.5 0.44 0.41 0.41 0.41 0.43 0.41 0.41 0.38 0.36 ...
 $ A32  : num  0.39 0.34 0.31 0.31 0.31 0.34 0.33 0.31 0.28 0.28 ...
 $ A33  : num  0.33 0.33 0.33 0.33 0.31 0.31 0.31 0.31 0.31 0.31 ...
 $ A34  : num  0.42 0.39 0.39 0.4 0.42 0.42 0.4 0.37 0.34 0.34 ...
 $ A35  : num  0.44 0.41 0.41 0.41 0.43 0.43 0.41 0.39 0.36 0.36 ...
 $ Class: **Factor** w/ 6 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 ...
```

My test data set looks just the same except that Class attribute is empty.I have   used this code to predict the Class for my test data set.

```
train <- read.csv("cse_DS_Intro2TRAIN.csv")

test <- read.csv("cse_DS_Intro2TEST.csv")

setDT(train)

setDT(test)

labels <- train$Class

ts_label <- test$Class

new_tr <- model.matrix(~.+0,data = train[,-c("Class"),with=F])

new_ts <- model.matrix(~.+0,data = test[,-c("Class"),with=F])

labels <- as.numeric(labels)-1

ts_label <- as.numeric(ts_label)-1

dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(data = new_tr,label = labels)

dtest <- xgb.DMatrix(data = new_ts,label=ts_label)

params <- list(
booster = "gbtree",
objective = "binary:logistic",
eta=0.3,
gamma=0,
max_depth=6,
min_child_weight=1,
subsample=1,
colsample_bytree=1
)

xgbcv <- xgb.cv(params = params
            ,data = dtrain
            ,nrounds = 100
            ,nfold = 5
            ,showsd = T
            ,stratified = T
            ,print.every.n = 10
            ,early.stop.round = 20
            ,maximize = F
)
```

When I run the above code, I get this error.

```
Error in xgb.iter.update(fd$bst, fd$dtrain, iteration - 1, obj) : 
[16:49:39] amalgamation/../src/objective/regression_obj.cc:108: label must 
be in [0,1] for logistic regression
```

Is it possible to predict a factor type data using XGBoost in R?

P.S. have used Random Forest to predict the class variable previously and it worked well.

Comment: Please use the appropriate tools to format your question. You can use `str()` function to show what your data looks like (at least I find it more intuitive).

Comment: Is your `Class` variable a string or factor? The error message implies that the function is expecting a target/class in binary numeric format.

Comment: @ulfelder It is a factor. I have included a screenshot of my training data set.

Comment: Screenshots don't make reproducible examples, which is what you'll probably need to post if you really want a solution to your problem.

Comment: Your target classes if they are like 1 and 2 just bring them down to 0 and 1. Then it should probably work.

Comment: @ulfelder I have changed my screenshots into postings. Thank you for the input.

Comment: @jilJungJuk My target classes are factors with the values {A,B,C,D,E,F}.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your target classes must start from 0 . Try the following example

```
library(xgboost)
data(agaricus.train)
data(agaricus.test)
train = agaricus.train

param = list("objective" = "binary:logistic" ,"eval_metric" = "logloss" ,
         "eta" =1 , "max.depth" = 2)
```

This model works since train$labels starts from 0 hence output probabilities will be for '1'

```
model <- xgboost(data = train$data, label = train$label,
             nrounds = 20, objective = "binary:logistic")
```

this model would not work. Notice the error message when you have it starting from 1.

```
 model <- xgboost(data = train$data, label = train$label+1,
             nrounds = 20, objective = "binary:logistic")
```

Just convert them into numeric type where they start from 0 that should work.

**Update:**
   Also since you have almost 6 classes the "objective" should be "multi:softmax" or "multi:softprob" where you should also include "num_class" parameter.

Comment: Thank you.Using softmax did the trick for me. As you said, first I converted my factor type variable into numeric  type variable. Then I used multi:softmax.                                      
              param <- list("objective" = "multi:softmax",
              "num_class" = numberOfClasses,
              "eval_metric" = "merror",
              "colsample_bytree" = .7,
              'subsample' = .7,
              "eta" = .01, "max.depth" = 6)                                                              I didn't get any errors this time.

Comment: Great ! Glad it helped. :-)